# SQL table won't build

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error saying there is a syntax error in this code,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reportcategorys` (
  `categoryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `subCategoryName` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryName`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`subCategoryName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reportsubcategorys` (
  `subCategoryName` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `categoryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subCategoryName`),
  FOREIGN KEY `Category_Name` (`categoryName`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I can't see the syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does that FOREIGN KEY point to?  No table that I can see.

The syntax ought to look like

```
FOREIGN KEY(subCategoryName) REFERENCES reportcategory(categoryName)
```

Substitute the table and its primary key as needed.

Table name ought to be singular: `reportCategory`, not `reportCategories`.  (Style preference, not syntax.)

Comment: Still not right.  What tables do they reference?  I see two wrong FOREIGN KEYS now instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

while describing Foreign key you need to write like

```
FOREIGN KEY(subCategoryName) REFERENCES reportcategory(categoryName)
```

for more information check this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html